# Google Maps Control for .NET Smart Device Application

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I am developing a GPS smart device application with VS 2008 and .NET compact framework 3.5 on windows 6.1 mobile, I wanna to show the current location to the user on windows mobile Form using an interactive google Map control. But I searched a lot for such a control through many sites uselessly can anyone tell me how to find this control or how to do it please ?

Answer (score 2):

GMaps.NET is the best in my opinion:

http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [project](http://mapcontrol.codeplex.com/) in codeplex you may try. Download the source code there is no binary for download.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also developing in the same environment and looking at adding navigation to our app. In our case the device will be in a vehicle so we want "Tom Tom" style nav rather than "top down" Google Maps.

We are using Resco controls which are excellent. They have recently released a navigation control that you can just drag on to a form. I'm hoping to evaluate this soon. This stuff isn't cheap but you might want to check out the demo if your project has the budget. Resco are an excellent company to deal with (no affiliation - just that they have made my app look cool and saved me a LOT of work).

http://www.resco.net/developer/mapnavigation/overview.aspx

Cheers
Mark